# Quote within quote

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

This is the situation : I am to mark a statement true or false with supporting statements from text. I like to put the extract in quotes to mean that it is the exact copy of the text. The problem is the original text begins with a quotation— say, with a direct speech. What's the solution?

- "  ' Let's look behind the counter, Gip,' l said"

Should it be like this? It is a binding rule that if a quotation contains a quotation within it the quote within quote is placed in single quotation.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what the context of the quotation is—because you haven't provided any narrative beyond it. What are the sentences that come before and after this that show how you've introduced the quote? Nor, unless it was a nonstandard piece of writing, do I think you included (1) the comma that would normally go after *Gip* but before the subsequent quotation mark or, (2) the period. Nested quotation marks are alternated. However, you can also use a text indent—depending on the length of the quotation—or you can use italics rather than quotation marks in some cases.

Comment: Double quotes are put by me to mean it's form the book. And single quote to mean it was there in the original text.

Comment: Yes, I get that. But how are you *introducing* the quotation? Where it is located in *your* text can determine how it would normally be presented. (Is it part of a larger paragraph? Is it a single-sentence paragraph? As I said, what comes before it and after it?)

Comment: In the text it was like this : "Let's look behind the counter, Gip," l said. " He's making fou of us."

Comment: Yes. But what is *your* text? You're quoting it. So you must be writing paragraphs or sentences of text before and after the quotation. What are they?  For example, (1) *In his book* Something or Other, *Somebody says, " 'Let's look behind the counter, Gip,' l said." He then goes on to say . . .*; or (2) *Somebody says the following: " 'Let's look behind the counter, Gip,' l said." Later, he says: . . .*

Comment: I understand the way it should be put.

Comment: If you did, you wouldn't necessarily ask this question. ;) What I'm trying to say is that ***your surrounding text*** can influence how the quotation is presented. Not all quotations need to be presented in an identical way. Unless you provide your surrounding text, the question can't be fully answered. (Aside from somebody making up many of their *own* examples to show how the context could change the presentation.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [reference](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/08/punctuating-around-quotation-marks.html). There are differences between AmE and BrE.

[image]
*Place other punctuation inside quotation marks when that punctuation is part of what is being quoted, such as a quoted question.